# There is an error using Spring Boot to receive the value using 'UserInfoDto' and then store the value in 'Users'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, web

This is view to receive the above values.
Press the Submit button at the end of the form tag to send the data.
(id, password, name, phone_number, ssn, city_name, town_name, street_name, zip_code, details)
Used : Mysql, Springboot, java, jpa, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>signuppage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="/css/sample.css">
    <link href="/css/listpage_copy.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/font.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="row g-3" id = "row_g-3_cumstom" action="/signup_execute" name = "user_info" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">이메일</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="최대 20자리 까지 입력가능" name = "id" maxlength="40">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">비밀번호</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="최대 20자리 까지 입력가능" name = "password" maxlength="20">
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">닉네임</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="최대 25자리까지 입력가능" name = "name" maxlength="25">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">전화번호</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="ex) 01012345678" pattern="[0-9]{11}" name = "phone" maxlength="12">
      </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">주민번호</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="13자리를 입려하세요." pattern="[0-9]{13}" name = "ssn" maxlength="13">
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
              남성
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
              여성
            </label>
          </div>



        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                도시명
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex) 서울특별시" aria-label="City" name = "city_name" maxlength="20">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                동명
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex) 논현동" aria-label="State" name = "town_name" maxlength="20">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                도로명
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex) 테헤란로 221길" aria-label="Zip" name = "street_name" maxlength="20">
            </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            우편번호
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex) 06049" aria-label="Zip" name = "zip_code" maxlength="20">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            상세주소
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex) 5층 505호" aria-label="Zip" name = "details" maxlength="20">
          </div>
          </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
              확인했음.
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >가입하기</button>
        </div>
    
      </form>
      
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

'Users' entity to register with DB.

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;


import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.UserInfoDto;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ssn","phone_number"})})
public class Users {

    @Column(name = "id", length = 40, updatable = false)
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", length = 12, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name =  "ssn", length = 13, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ssn;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "point")
    private Long point;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postedUser")
    private List<PostInfo> uploadedPost = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<PointHistory> pointHistories = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    private Dates dates;

    public Users(UserInfoDto userInfoDto){
        this.setId(userInfoDto.getId());
        this.setPassword(userInfoDto.getPassword());
        this.setPhoneNumber(userInfoDto.getPhoneNumber());
        this.setSsn(userInfoDto.getSsn());
        this.setPoint(0L);

        Address address = new Address(
                userInfoDto.getCityName(),
                userInfoDto.getTownName(),
                userInfoDto.getStreetName(),
                userInfoDto.getZipCode(),
                userInfoDto.getDetailsCode()
        );

        this.setAddress(address);

        List<PostInfo> postInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PointHistory> pointHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.setUploadedPost(postInfoList);
        this.setPointHistories(pointHistoryList);

        Dates dates = new Dates(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());

        this.setDates(dates);
    }
}
```

This is Embedded type 'Address' inside 'Users'

```
package My_Project.integration.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    @Column(name = "city_name", length = 20, nullable = false) //도시명
    private String cityName;

    @Column(name = "town_name", length = 20) //동명
    private String townName;

    @Column(name = "street_name", length = 20, nullable = false) //도로명
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "zip_code", length = 20) // 우편번호
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "details",length = 20) //상세주소
    private String detailsCode;

    protected Address() {
    }

}
```

This is a Dto class that receives a value instead of 'Users'.

```
package My_Project.integration.entity.Dto;

import My_Project.integration.entity.PointHistory;
import My_Project.integration.entity.PostInfo;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
public class UserInfoDto {

    private String id;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String ssn;

    private String cityName;
    private String townName;
    private String streetName;
    private String zipCode;
    private String detailsCode;

    private Long point;
    private List<PointHistory> pointHistories;
    private List<PostInfo> postInfos;

    public UserInfoDto(String id, String password, String name, String phoneNumber, String ssn, String cityName, String townName, String streetName, String zipCode, String detailsCode, Long point, List<PointHistory> pointHistories, List<PostInfo> postInfos) {
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.ssn = ssn;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.townName = townName;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.detailsCode = detailsCode;
        this.point = point;
        this.pointHistories = pointHistories;
        this.postInfos = postInfos;
    }

    public UserInfoDto() {
    }
}
```

I want to put the values on 'Users' through 'UserInfoDto'. But It's doesn't work with error code above. What should I fix?

Error code

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : My_Project.integration.entity.Users.address.cityName; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : My_Project.integration.entity.Users.address.cityName
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:294)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy109.save(Unknown Source)
    at My_Project.integration.service.UserService.addUsers(UserService.java:26)
    at My_Project.integration.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$636d190f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at My_Project.integration.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7615f959.addUsers(<generated>)
    at My_Project.integration.controller.SignupPageController.signUp(SignupPageController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : My_Project.integration.entity.Users.address.cityName
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy105.merge(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy105.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:669)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exception it seams that the field cityName is null somehow when you do the mapping. As there is a not null constraint on this field this causes the issue